# Creating VBA function that converts minutes to hh:mm:ss

Tags: vba, excel, time-format

I am trying to take a minute value (such as 3.83 minutes) and convert it to the hh:mm:ss time format (which I know is 0:03:50)

For some reason, the .NumberFormat as recorded from a macro isn't working and giving me a #VALUE! error.

```
    Function MINtoHMS(MIN)
    MIN = MIN / (24 * 60)
    MINtoHMS = MIN
    MINtoHMS.NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss;@"
    End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-Edit- To use as an add-in

Excel Add-In: http://www.filedropper.com/mintohms

Create a class module named SheetChangeHandler with the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Err
    If InStr(Target.Formula, "=MINtoHMS") Then
        Target.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
Err:
End Sub
```

Add a module with the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public MySheetHandler As SheetChangeHandler

Sub Auto_Open()
   Set MySheetHandler = New SheetChangeHandler
End Sub

Function MINtoHMS(MIN)
    MIN = MIN / (24 * 60)
    MINtoHMS = MIN
End Function
```

Click File > Save As > Excel 97-2003 Add-In (*.xla) > Save

Click File > Options > Add-Ins

Click "Go..." next to Manage: Excel Add-ins

Check the box next to the add-in you just created

Click "OK"

Comment: For one reason or another, after the function runs, the value in the cell is locked. Meaning that when I try to change the value to another format, nothing happens. It's almost as if the output was a text format. Another indication that it is now a text format is the value is automatically oriented to the left in the cell.

Comment: This does not change the cell formatting. All it does is convert the number to the desired format and output the result. I don't understand why you are trying to change the format to something different after converting it to h:mm:ss. If that is not the desired format then why change it to that at all?

Comment: Since it hasn't changed to the format hh:mm:ss, but been output as a text format with that syntax, I am unable to have other cells interact with it (I am averaging times in the hh:mm:ss  format).

Comment: Add the above code to the worksheet in which you are using the function and change the function to output a number and that should give you the desired result. If you are using the function on multiple sheets it can be changed to work on every worksheet in your workbook.

Comment: Is there anyway to include the private subroutine in an add-in, so it'll work on all worksheets? Also, when placing it in the ThisWorkbook object, I could not get it to function.

Comment: I added workbook code above. That will make it work on all sheets.

Comment: However, there's no way to place this ThisWorkbook code in an add-in, so it could work on any Excel file opened?

Comment: See above for use as an add-in

Answer (score 1):

First, You cannot change the format of an Excel Cell through its Formula.  A Cell's formula can *only* assign to the value of a cell (or range).

Secondly, You really ought to declare some data-types in your functions, which will prevent a host of mysterious errors and other strange results.

Something like this should be fine:

```
Function MINtoHMS(MIN As Double) As Date
    MIN = MIN / (24 * 60)
    MINtoHMS = MIN
End Function
```

The only way to absolutely control what is seen through a function, would be to return a formatted string instead, as Ripster shows in his/her answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try these following methods.

```
DAYS = Format(Int([Expr3]/86400), "00") - will correctly display days
HOURS = Format(Int(([Expr3])/3600) - ((Int([Expr3]*86400)/3600), "00") - DOES NOT CORRECTLY display correct hours
HOURS = Format(Int([Expr3]/3600),"00") - What will display hours
MINUTES = Int(([Expr3]-(Int([Expr3]/3600)*3600))/60)
SECONDS = Format((([Expr3] Mod 60)),"00")

dTotalSeconds = DateDiff("S", Now(), dChristmasDate)
    iDays = Int(dTotalSeconds / 86400)
    iHours = Int((dTotalSeconds Mod 86400) / 3600)
    iMinutes = Int(((dTotalSeconds Mod 86400) Mod 3600) / 60)
    iSeconds = ((dTotalSeconds Mod 86400) Mod 3600) Mod 60
```

'    By Using this function you can convert minutes to hh:mm:ss

```
    Public Function HMStoSec(strHMS As String) As Long
        HMStoSec = Split(strHMS, ":")(0) * 3600 + _
                   Split(strHMS, ":")(1) * 60 + _
                   Split(strHMS, ":")(2)
    End Function
```